# how to get only fully matched string from match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match `"test"` or `"test,"` from a string like

```
"test, testhellowowo, wowtest,"
```

**Attempt 1**

```
test[,]?
```

it will match all three since all of the string include the `test` regardless what comes after.

**Attempt 2**

```
^test[,]?$
```

it won't match any unless the string is `test` or `test,`

**Expected results**

```
"test, testhellowowo, wowtest,".match(x) // should match `test,` 
"testhellowowo, wowtest,".match(x)  // should not match anything
```

Comment: that did it, if you answer I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries

```
/\btest\b/g
```

They match at

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include the punctuation mark you could also do `/^test[,]?$/gm`

^ matches beginning of string
$ matches end of string